# Python JSON encode mixed data

Tags: python, json, django

Is there any way to JSON encode mixed type of data in Python/Django?

For instance:

```
response = {}
response['redirect'] = True
response['post_list'] = Menu.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("menuitem_set", queryset=MenuItem.objects.filter(pk__gt=0), to_attr="some_items")).all()
response['last_post'] = Menu.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("menuitem_set", queryset=MenuItem.objects.filter(pk__gt=0), to_attr="some_items")).get(pk=1)
response['method'] = 'get'
```

I want to serialize `response` object as JSON without looping and creating a dict. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps):

> Serialize *obj* to a JSON formatted **str**.

---

**Example:**

```
response = {}
response['foo'] = 'bar';

import json
print json.dumps(response)  # {"foo": "bar"}
```